# Issues with cycle render using 3 GPUs - Possible problem with one of the cards?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I am having a problem relating to Cycles Rendering. I have 3 970s (not in SLI) and one of them seems to not like the Cycles rendering. In every case I have tried it will throw out a

> CUDA error: ILLEGAL_ADDRESS in cuCtxSynchronize()

and will not render anything.

I am using the BMW test .blend available on the demo pages. I can render the file with the other 2 970s using the same settings, however if I try and use either 970x2 or x3 in the compute options it will render 1 or 2 panels respectively (presumably from the other cards being used) and then give me the same error.

I have also tried it on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 and receive the same error each time.

Is this just a case of an RMA for the card giving me errors? Is there some logging I can turn on to give me more details? I can't find anything online about this kind of error.

Comment: Try removing the two crds that you know work well and keep only the suspect card make a test and see what happens.

Comment: Also when running three cards make sure your power supply and cooling is adecuate.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. With only the suspect card in the PC booted fine but still gave me `CUDA error: ILLEGAL_ADDRESS in cuCtxSynchronize()`. I also tried a GPU test program and it locked up with minor artifacting immediately.

We have a Corsair HX1200 for power so that shouldn't be an issue, plenty of airflow in the case too. I was monitoring temps and they were barely getting above 50.